# Unexpected escape character error in SparkSql

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read the json file through the code
`val i = sqlContext.jsonFile("file_name.json")` using scala
.It gives me error "unexpected escape character: a".

When i enclose this line within try catch, even then it gives the same error.

```
try{
val i = sqlContext.jsonFile("File_name.json")
}catch{
case ex: Exception=>println("error")
}
```

Why is this happening? Anybody has any idea? How can i read my json file?

I am trying to learn SparkSql.

Comment: Please write down the json file so that other people can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Please post complete error message